# Docker linux: How to start multiple console/terminals for one running container?

Tags: linux, docker, terminal, console

I'm using below command to run docker,

```
docker run -it centos:6.5 bash
```

It starts bash with root user, no problem.

But I wish to have multiple terminals to connect to it and do different things. I found `attach` command will only duplicate a terminal window which all input/output will be propagated. It doesn't solve my requirement.

How to do this?

Comment: Another alternative would be to install screen, execute it with a simple `screen` and then create additional shells with `CTRL + a` `+` `c`. Then you can cycle through the shells with `CTRL + a` `+` `SPACE`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Once the container is running, you should be able to use `docker exec` to run an additional Bash session in the same container.

When your first container is running, use `docker ps` to find its *Container ID* (the first column in the `docker ps` output), e.g. `4a7afcdeb729`, then run the following:

```
docker exec -it 4a7afcdeb729 bash
```

This should open a new terminal session in the container.

Comment: This is what I expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems to exit immediately. How can we enter the container in a second interactive shell?  Ok found it: you might want to *edit the answer* to include `-it`

Comment: `-it` worked with `exec` for me -- if you want to "enter the container in a second interactive shell", `docker exec -it 4a7afcdeb729 bash" is right

Comment: You are of course right, I added the missing flag in the answer. Thanks for adding the comment!